# C# ValidationResult value equality assertion fails with Assert.AreEqual

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a simple ValidationRule implementation :

```
public class IntegerRangeRule : ValidationRule
{
    public Int32 Max { get; set; }
    public Int32 Min { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int integer;

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Field cannot be empty");
        }

        if (Int32.TryParse((string) value, out integer))
        {
            if((integer < Min) || (integer > Max))
                return new ValidationResult(false, string.Format("Enter a value between {0} and {1}.", Min, Max));
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal characters: " + (string)value);
        }

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

I wrote the following unit test for the `Validation` method:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void ValidateTest_InputTooSmall()
{
    //Setup
    var target = new IntegerRangeRule()
    {
        Max = 100,
        Min = 1
    };
    var expected = new ValidationResult(false, "Enter a value between 1 and 100.");

    //Exercise
    var actual = target.Validate("0", null);

    //Verify
    Assert.AreEqual(expected.ErrorContent, actual.ErrorContent);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected.IsValid, actual.IsValid);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected.GetHashCode(), actual.GetHashCode());
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Here is the catch.

The first three assertions all pass. But the last one fails.

If I replace the

```
...
    if (Int32.TryParse((string) value, out integer))
    {
        if((integer < Min) || (integer > Max))
            return new ValidationResult(false, string.Format("Enter a value between {0} and {1}.", Min, Max));
    }
...
```

with a constant string.

```
...
    if (Int32.TryParse((string) value, out integer))
    {
        if((integer < Min) || (integer > Max))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Enter a value between 1 and 100.");
    }
...
```

The last assertion will pass.

I dont understand what is causing the problem here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ValidationResult contains this in [Equals](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ValidationResult.cs#d0f91de78061d24b#references):

```
return (IsValid == vr.IsValid) && (ErrorContent == vr.ErrorContent);
```

Since `ErrorContent` is an object, this is a reference comparison, not a value comparison. In your case you are generating a new string using `String.Format` and comparing that reference to a literal, so the result is always false. When you change it to the same literal string it passes because literals are interned by the CLR.

Meanwhile your testing framework is probably calling `Object.Equals(object, object)` inside its `Assert.AreEqual` method, which invokes String's overridden Equals method. This does a value comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw. Em... It would certainly help if I had access to the source code in the first place. Since ErrorContent is an object and reference equality is check. How come the first assertion Assert.AreEqual(expected.ErrorContent, actual.ErrorContent); didnt fail?

Comment: @FrankLiu You have access to the framework source code at referencesource.microsoft.com.

Comment: @FrankLiu I know MSTest/VSTest uses the static `Object.Equals` method. NUnit might do something different (like check for string). Either way, it is doing a value comparison.

Comment: Sorry, I was using MSTest/VSTest

Comment: When executing Assert.AreEqual(expected.ErrorContent, actual.ErrorContent); The test framework calls the static [Object.Equals(object, object)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs) So the objA.Equals(objB) turns into a value equality check?

Comment: @FrankLiu Yes, and that is a virtual call which for strings checks value equality.